# Number of couples of positive integers whose LCM is d

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic

Let $d$ be a positive integer with $t$ prime factors, and without any square factor. (I translate that as $d=p_1p_2...p_t$, with $p_i$ prime, with exponent always equal to $1$).

Show that the number of couples $(x,y)$ ($x,y>0$) such that $LCM(x,y)=d$  is $3^t$.

I have a problem because it seems to me that that number should be $2^t$, or $2^t-1$.

Here is what I do :
to find a couple $(x,y)$ that verifies the conditions, one just has to find $x$, because the choice of $y$ seems to follow from the choice of $x$. For instance, if $x$ is $p_1$, then $y$ has to be $p_2p_3...p_t$. If $x$ is $p_2p_3$, then $y$ has to be $p_1p_4...p_t$. Is this false ?

Then the number of choices for $x$ is : first, each single $p_i$ ; then, each $p_ip_j$, so there are $\binom{t}{2}$ possibilities ; then each $p_ip_jp_k$, so $\binom{t}{3}$ possibilities, and this way up to $t-1$. If we add the couple $(1,d)$, which corresponds to $\binom{t}{0}$, then the number of possibilities is the sum of all binomials $\binom{t}{k}$, for $k$ going from $0$ to $t-1$, which should be $2^t-1$.

So why $3^t$ ?

Comment: If $x$ is $p_1$, then $y$ could be either $p_2p_3\cdots p_t$ or $p_1p_2p_3\cdots p_t$. (Otherwise, your calculation of the number of choices of $x$ is right, except that it's not clear why you stop at $t-1$ and don't include the case $x = p_1p_2\cdots p_t$, which would give $2^t$.)

Comment: You can also count the number of choices for $x$ by saying that the primes that go into it form a subset of $\{p_1, p_2, \dots, p_t\}$, and there are $2^t$ such subsets (for each $p_i$, it has two choices: it could either go into $x$ or not). Similarly, try counting the number of pairs $(x, y)$ with $\operatorname{lcm}(x, y) = d$, by considering the possibilities for each $p_i$: does it go into $x$ or not, does it go into $y$ or not, what are the choices?

Comment: Yes, some of the factors of y could also be factors of x. thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** For each $p_i$ there is $3$ cases:

be a factor of $x$, or

be a factor of $y$ or

be a factor of both.

Comment: I get it. The intersection of the sets of the factors of $x$ and $y$ need not be empty. thanks !

Comment: @Asinus, your welcome!